# How to post the username and password securly from device to url

Tags: ios, http-post

Hi in my Application i have Login option with username and password I'm passing the username and password through URL to my php script and getting response from the URL and the it will navigate to next view.

I want to know to pass the data with securely from the device to my url My code.

```
 NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@myril?username=%@&password=%@",usern.text,pass.text];

NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

NSLog(@"response %@",strResult);
```

In my above code I'm passing the data directly in my URL please tell how to pass it with post method securely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://iostwist.blogspot.com/2012/07/send-data-by-post-method.html

This is a small tutorial to show you how to pass using POST method

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    NSString *dataSendingStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myril?username=%@&password=%@",usern.text,pass.text];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Your URL"];
   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
   [request addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
   [request setHTTPBody:[dataSendingStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
   NSError *errorReturned = nil;
   NSURLResponse *theResponse =[[NSURLResponse alloc]init];
   NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&theResponse error:&errorReturned];
   NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"String %@",responseData);
```

Cheers...